# How to populate an unbound text in report from table?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm sending a report to each customer a daily recap from the day. Instead of creating different reports for each customer, i'm using one report and changing the SQL Where statement of the query used to supply the report. I'm using a loop to change the query then exporting the linked report as a pdf and emailing them out. I'm attempting to get the customer's name as the title of the report in an unbound text. I can get the customer's name easily during the loop, but how do I populate the unbound text box in the report with the customer's name before I export it as a pdf?

```
Public Function querydef()
Const cdoSendUsingPickup = 1
Const cdoSendUsingPort = 2
Const cdoAnonymous = 0
' Use basic (clear-text) authentication.
Const cdoBasic = 1
' Use NTLM authentication
Const cdoNTLM = 2 'NTLM

Set imsg = CreateObject("CDO.Message")
Set iconf = CreateObject("CDO.Configuration")
Set flds = iconf.Fields


    ' send one copy with SMTP server (with autentication)
schema = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/"
flds.Item(schema & "sendusing") = cdoSendUsingPort
flds.Item(schema & "smtpserver") = "smtp.gmail.com"
flds.Item(schema & "smtpserverport") = 25
flds.Item(schema & "smtpauthenticate") = cdoBasic
flds.Item(schema & "sendusername") = "email.com"
flds.Item(schema & "sendpassword") = "abc"
flds.Item(schema & "smtpusessl") = True
flds.Update

Dim Files As Variant
Dim WhereQ As String
Dim db As DAO.Database
Set db = CurrentDb
Dim qdf As DAO.querydef

Set MYDB = CurrentDb
Set myrec = MYDB.OpenRecordset("report emails NEW")
myrec.Move First

Do Until myrec.EOF

WhereQ = myrec!whereto

Files = "C:\Users\XYZ" & myrec!reporttitle & " " & Year(Date) & 
     Format(Month(Date), "00") & Format(Day(Date), "00") & ".pdf"

If myrec!Files = -1 Then

Set qdf = db.QueryDefs("REPORT TEST")
qdf.SQL = "SELECT [Email Files].[Acct #], [Email Files].bs, [Email 
          Files].Filed, [Email Files].com, emailfiles([newpx]) AS npx, 
          IIf([Frac]='X','',[frac]) AS Expr1, comm([com]) AS comm, 
          sortmon([com]) AS [month], [Email Files].[2yr], * FROM [Email 
          Files] WHERE " & WhereQ & "; "  '"




If DCount("BS", "REPORT TEST") > 0 Then

    DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, "REPORT TEST REPORT FILES", 
    acFormatPDF, Files


    With imsg

        .To = myrec!testemail
        .From = "sending email"
        .Subject = myrec!reporttitlefile & " for " & Format(Month(Date), 
                 "00") & "/" & Format(Day(Date), "00") & "/" & Year(Date)
        .HTMLBody = ""
        .AddAttachment (Files)

        Set .Configuration = iconf
        .Send

    End With

    Set iconf = Nothing
    Set imsg = Nothing
    Set flds = Nothing

    Else

    Set imsg = CreateObject("CDO.Message")
    Set iconf = CreateObject("CDO.Configuration")
    Set flds = iconf.Fields


    ' send one copy with SMTP server (with autentication)
    schema = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/"
    flds.Item(schema & "sendusing") = cdoSendUsingPort
    flds.Item(schema & "smtpserver") = "smtp.gmail.com"
    flds.Item(schema & "smtpserverport") = 25
    flds.Item(schema & "smtpauthenticate") = cdoBasic
    flds.Item(schema & "sendusername") = "email.com"
    flds.Item(schema & "sendpassword") = "abc"
    flds.Item(schema & "smtpusessl") = True
    flds.Update


    With imsg

        .To = myrec!testemail
        .From = "email.com"
        .Subject = myrec!Add & " has no files for " & Format(Month(Date), 
         "00") & "/" & Format(Day(Date), "00") & "/" & Year(Date)
        .HTMLBody = "Please let us know if you have a discrepancy."

        Set .Configuration = iconf
        .Send


    End With

    Set iconf = Nothing
    Set imsg = Nothing
    Set flds = Nothing
End If
Else
    'do nothing
End If
qdf.SQL = "SELECT [Email Files].[Acct #], [Email Files].bs, [Email 
Files].Filed, [Email Files].com, emailfiles([newpx]) AS npx, 
IIf([Frac]='X','',[frac]) AS Expr1, comm([com]) AS comm, sortmon([com]) 
AS [month], [Email Files].[2yr], * FROM [Email Files] "

myrec.MoveNext
Loop
End Function
```

Comment: Why don't you use a bound control for the customer name?

Answer (score 0):

I got your question and here you my humble solution with the attached MS Access Database , just follow up these instructions below:

1-  Create a new Module named as Module1 then declare this global variable that goes and comes among the whole database level, either forms or reports, like this:

Option Compare Database

Global GlbRepInfo As String

2-  Put this code in the commend button from the original form that will show up the report, like this:

Private Sub CmdRepEmp_Click()

CmbEmp.SetFocus

GlbRepInfo = CmbEmp.Text

DoCmd.Close acReport, "RepSat", acSaveNo

DoCmd.OpenReport "RepEmp", acViewPreview, , "EmpID=" & CmbEmp.Value

End Sub

3-  Finally, put this code in your target report, especially on load event, like this:

Private Sub Report_Open(Cancel As Integer)

LblRepInfo.Caption = "Employees Report: " & vbNewLine & GlbRepInfo

End Sub

The DB linke:
[enter link description here](http://www.mediafire.com/file/ims9sxff9448c0w/MSAccessPassReportTitle.rar/file)

[image]